# Number of clients which buy more than 3 different CDs during every vist in shop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables
First with names of CDs, id and price for each.

```
CD
ID   NAME          PRICE
1    Maria Carey    5
2    Michael Jakson 2
3    Rihanna        3
4    Beyonce        2
5    Jay Z          3
```

Second one is with specific data

```
SALES
    CLIENT_ID   CD_ID  AMOUNT SHOP      DATE
    1             12     34   New York   2000-03-12
    2             12     4   Los Angeles 2000-03-14
    3             42     3    Chicago    2001-03-24
    4             32     16   New York   2001-05-19
    2             12     16   New York   2001-05-19
    2             42     16   New York   2001-05-19
    4             32     16   New York   2001-05-19
```

My idea for solving it

```
   SELECT DISTINCT Sales.Client_id
    FROM Sales s
    GROUP BY s.Client_id, s.Amount, s.Date
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 3;
```

but it doesn't work. Can You help me?

Answer (score 1):

You want to start with the number of CDs purchased in a visit.  Assuming that a "visit" is a client/shop/date combination, then this does that calculation:

```
SELECT s.Client_id, s.shop, s.Date, count(distinct cd_id) as cnt
FROM Sales s
GROUP BY s.Client_id, s.shop, s.Date;
```

Note:  Your data cannot differentiate a client who goes to the same shop twice in one day.

Next, the question is whether a customer always purchases at least 3 CDs.  That is another level of aggregation, at the customer level.  This is where you want to do the filtering:

```
SELECT ClientId, MIN(cnt) as minimum_cds
FROM (SELECT s.Client_id, s.shop, s.Date, count(distinct cd_id) as cnt
      FROM Sales s
      GROUP BY s.Client_id, s.shop, s.Date
     ) csd
GROUP BY ClientId
HAVING MIN(cnt) >= 3;
```

Comment: Thx! Now it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server 2012+ you can try this:

```
  Select countQuery.Client_id from
    (
      select distinct s.Client_id , sum(1) 
      over (partition by s.Client_id,s.CD_ID) counts3
      from #Sales s
    ) countQuery
    Where countQuery.counts3>=3
```